# What is the definition of 'perverse whim'

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, definition

What is the definition of 'perverse whim'

I can't seem to find the definition of it on the internet.

There is only the definition of perverse

> Perverse
> Pronunciation: /pəˈvəːs/
> ADJECTIVE

> 1. Showing a deliberate and obstinate desire to behave in a way that is
>    unreasonable or unacceptable: Kate’s perverse decision not to
>    cooperate held good More example sentences Synonyms

> 2. Contrary to the
>    accepted or expected standard or practice: in two general elections
>    the outcome was quite perverse

> Oxford Dictionary (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/perverse)

I saw this word in an extract from a story which is in this sentence:

> She looked at me as if I had all the answers and was keeping them from her from some **perverse whim** as if I had them hidden in the inside pocket of my blazer.

Comment: Did you look up "whim" and try combining those?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it needs more explanation of why the dictionary definition didn't help you understand the sentence. Why do the definitions of whim and perverse not help you understand "perverse whim"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **perverse** = odd, not usual or ordinary
>   **whim** = a capricious notion or desire

**perverse whim** is a desire to do something odd (not an *odd desire*, which would mean something different) for self satisfaction or entertainment.

The passage is saying "she" thought "he" was withholding something as if it were at his finger tips but she **felt** that he didn't want her to have it **and** that he derived some joy by not letting her have it.

Comment: Perverse doesn't mean odd. It means being difficult or unhelpful in a way that suggests some sort of malice or a contrarian nature on the person's part. A perverse whim is a capricious desire to be difficult to someone just for the sake of being difficult.